# Sum of array of dictionaries depending on value condition pyspark (spark structured streaming)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have the following schema

```
        tick_by_tick_schema = StructType([
            StructField('localSymbol', StringType()),
            StructField('time', StringType()),
            StructField('open', StringType()),
            StructField('previous_price', StringType()),
            StructField('tickByTicks', ArrayType(StructType([
                StructField('price', StringType()),
                StructField('size', StringType()),
                StructField('specialConditions', StringType()),
            ])))
        ])
```

and I have the following dataframe (in spark structured streaming):

```
+-----------+--------------------------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|localSymbol|time                            |previous_price|tickByTicks                                         |
+-----------+--------------------------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|BABA       |2021-06-10 19:25:38.154245+00:00|213.76        |[{213.75, 100, }]                                   |
|BABA       |2021-06-10 19:25:38.155229+00:00|213.76        |[{213.75, 100, }, {213.78, 100, }, {213.78, 200, }] |
|BABA       |2021-06-10 19:25:39.662033+00:00|213.73        |[{213.72, 100, }]                                   |
|BABA       |2021-06-10 19:25:39.662655+00:00|213.72        |[{213.72, 100, }, {213.73, 100, }]                  |                                                                                
+-----------+--------------------------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to create two columns depending on the next logic:

```
Column_low: WHEN tickByTicks.price < previous_price THEN sum(tickByTicks.size)
Column_high: when tickByTicks.price > previous_price THEN sum(tickByTicks.size)
```

the result will be:

```
+-----------+--------------------------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+
|localSymbol|time                            |previous_price|tickByTicks                                         |Column_low|Column_high|
+-----------+--------------------------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+
|BABA       |2021-06-10 19:25:38.154245+00:00|213.76        |[{213.75, 100, }]                                   |100       |0          |
|BABA       |2021-06-10 19:25:38.155229+00:00|213.76        |[{213.75, 100, }, {213.78, 100, }, {213.78, 200, }] |100       |300        |
|BABA       |2021-06-10 19:25:39.662033+00:00|213.73        |[{213.72, 100, }]                                   |100       |0          |
|BABA       |2021-06-10 19:25:39.662655+00:00|213.72        |[{213.72, 100, }, {213.73, 100, }]                  |0         |100        |                                                                  
+-----------+--------------------------------+--------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+
```

I have tried to do something similar but I have not achieved the expected result

```
        tick_by_tick_data_processed = kafka_df_structured_with_tick_by_tick_data_values.select(
            f.col('localSymbol'),
            f.col('time'),
            f.col('previous_price'),
            f.col('tickByTicks'),
            f.expr("aggregate(filter(tickByTicks.size, x -> x > previous_price), 0D, (x, acc) -> acc + x)")
        ).show(30,False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test my solution, but I think this may work:

```py
tick_by_tick_data_processed = kafka_df_structured_with_tick_by_tick_data_values.select(
            f.col('localSymbol'),
            f.col('time'),
            f.col('previous_price'),
            f.col('tickByTicks'),
            f.expr("aggregate(tickByTicks, 0D, (acc, tick) -> IF(tick.price < previous_price, acc + tick.size, acc))").alias("Column_low"),
            f.expr("aggregate(tickByTicks, 0D, (acc, tick) -> IF(tick.price > previous_price, acc + tick.size, acc))").alias("Column_high"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works using explode and sum function

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

data = [
           ("BABA", "2021-06-10 19:25:38.154245+00:00" ,"213.76" ,[("213.75", "100")] ),
           ("BABA", "2021-06-10 19:25:38.155229+00:00" ,"213.76" ,[("213.75", "100"),("213.78", "100"),("213.78", "200")] ),
           ("BABA", "2021-06-10 19:25:39.662033+00:00" ,"213.73" ,[("213.72", "100")]  ),
           ("BABA", "2021-06-10 19:25:39.662655+00:00" ,"213.72" ,[("213.72", "100"),("213.73", "100")]  ),
            ]

tick_by_tick_schema = StructType([
    StructField('localSymbol', StringType()),
    StructField('time', StringType()),
    StructField('previous_price', StringType()),
    StructField('tickByTicks', ArrayType(StructType([
        StructField('price', StringType()),
        StructField('size', StringType())
    ])))
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=tick_by_tick_schema)
df = df.withColumn("idx", monotonically_increasing_id())
df=df.withColumn("col3", explode(df.tickByTicks))
df.createOrReplaceTempView("calc")
spark.sql("select localSymbol,time,previous_price,idx,tickByTicks, sum (case when col3.price < previous_price then col3.size else 0 end) as Column_low ,sum(case when col3.price > previous_price then col3.size else 0 end) as Column_low from calc group by localSymbol,time,previous_price,idx,tickByTicks ").drop("idx").show(truncate=0)
```

Results

```
+-----------+--------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+----------+----------+
|localSymbol|time                            |previous_price|tickByTicks                                  |Column_low|Column_low|
+-----------+--------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+----------+----------+
|BABA       |2021-06-10 19:25:39.662033+00:00|213.73        |[[213.72, 100]]                              |100.0     |0.0       |
|BABA       |2021-06-10 19:25:38.154245+00:00|213.76        |[[213.75, 100]]                              |100.0     |0.0       |
|BABA       |2021-06-10 19:25:39.662655+00:00|213.72        |[[213.72, 100], [213.73, 100]]               |0.0       |100.0     |
|BABA       |2021-06-10 19:25:38.155229+00:00|213.76        |[[213.75, 100], [213.78, 100], [213.78, 200]]|100.0     |300.0     |
+-----------+--------------------------------+--------------+---------------------------------------------+----------+----------+

>>>
```